# Is it possible to update only part of an app in the App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

My app relies on an external service that might change its output any time without warning, so I would need a completly new function to parse it. Is there anyway to update my service parser without having to re-submit the whole app for review? Otherwise part of my app would be broken during the time to develop and review the new parser. I was told I cannot use bundles for this, so I really am clueless how to solve this problem.

Comment: Wrong assumption, it is a service

Comment: Depending on the range of changes anticipated, one might be able to define an interpretative language to handle the interfacing, vs placing the function in "hard" C/Objective-C code.  This would be a practical approach especially if the anticipated changes were things like changing the names and positions of data values in the downloaded data.

Comment: Sounds like a crappy service to be relying on. Replacing that dependency might be a good long-term goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't solve that problem completely on the client side.

Depending on the output format of the external service, and the methods you use to parse its output, you might have the option to store a file in a server that contains information about the current output format of the external service. Then your app can use the meta-data in that file to determine how to do the parsing.

You can also develop a simple web service that wraps the external service. Then your app can use the web service instead of the original service, and whenever the output of the original service is changed, you can quickly update your web service to make your app continue functioning properly.

Comment: The service is so complex that I would probably need to interpret some scripting language file that can properly describe it (iex.: lua) but I think this is also against apple rules, no?

Comment: No, I don't think so, because you aren't downloading a script to execute it on the device. But if the service is complex, then clearly, the wrapper service is the way to go. In fact I would prefer that method regardless of the complexity of the service because it is clearer and easier to develop and maintain.

Comment: But if the service describes the app behaviour is it a "no no"?

Comment: Well, the old guidelines banned downloading any kind of code that's gonna be interpreted. Nothing was stated about data that's gonna be "parsed". The new guidelines only ban 

`2.7 Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected
2.8 Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected`.

Nothing about even some interpreted code. So, even though there's a huge difference between the theory and practice of rejecting apps by the reviewers, downloading data that's gonna be parsed shouldn't cause any problems.

Don't confuse parsing data with executing interpreted code.